# .change() not work after .append()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like detect all changes on input and select.

For do this I have a function :

```
$('input, select').on("change", function(){

   addSelect(); // This function add a select when another select is clicked

   // Some others functions ...
});
```

When I change the value of a first select the function addSelect() works and a second select is created below the first.
But when I clicked on this second select the function .on("change") not working.

If I click on the first the function works...

Can you help me ? Thank's you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `.on()` like below for dynamically created elements.

**[API for .on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**

```
//This will delegate change event to the all input and select under document

$(document).on("change",'input, select', function(){

   addSelect(); // This function add a select when another select is clicked

   // Some others functions ...
});
```

Comment: Working fine. Thank's for this tip !